# ImageComboBox for VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to use images inside a ComboBox instead of strings? I've seen post regarding the ImageComboBox control but it seems that I couldn't find any resource how and where to download the said control so I could use it in my project that I'm working on.

Thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

To be able to use the Image Combo Box, you have to do the following:

Insert the control from the Insert menu on the developer tools tab:

[image: ActiveX]

If you press the highlighted button, a new menu appears.
Search for "Microsoft ImageComboBox Control, version XX"

Then you are able to insert the desired combobox.

Comment: ...and how to add images, etc?